# WCF Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf

Try to save image through my WCF service. I noticed that with small file size **3619** it works fine but with big file size **52857** , it doesn't.

Here is my config file

```
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MaxbasicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give a binding a name, it has to be explicitly set on your service with the bindingConfiguration property.  Using `bindingConfiguration="MaxbasicHttpBinding"`on your service configuration (see below) should work.  If you do not have a service configuration, then removing `name="MaxbasicHttpBinding"` from your definition will make it apply to all endpoints.

```
<services>
  <service name="Your.ServiceName">
    <endpoint name="Your.ServiceName.EndpointName"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="MaxbasicHttpBinding"
              contract="Your.Service.Contract" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation